# display the total based on the inputted amount in the datagridview

Tags: vb.net

i have a textbox where i can input any amount for example 3,000.00, then a datagridview that looks like

```
Category | Amount  
Supmat   | 2,000  
POL      | 500  
Others   | 400  
POL      | 500
```

to get the total i used this code

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
    If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Category").Value = "Supplies/Materials" Then
        supmat += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Amount").Value
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Category").Value = "Legal Expenses" Then
        legal += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Amount").Value
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Category").Value = "POL" Then
        pol += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Amount").Value
    ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Category").Value = "Others" Then
        oth += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Amount").Value
    End If

If CDec(txtFund.Text) > supmat Then
        supmat1 = supmat
        remain = CDec(txtFund.Text) - supmat
        If legal > 0 Then
            If remain > legal Then
                legal1 = legal
                remain2 = remain - legal
                If pol > 0 Then
                    If remain2 > pol Then
                        pol1 = pol
                        remain3 = remain2 - pol
                        If oth > 0 Then
                            If remain3 > oth Then
                                oth1 = oth
                            Else
                                oth1 = remain3
                            End If
                        Else
                            oth1 = remain3
                        End If
                    Else
                        pol1 = remain2
                        oth1 = 0
                    End If
                ElseIf oth > 0 Then
                    If remain2 > oth Then
                        oth1 = oth
                    Else
                        oth1 = remain2
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                legal1 = remain
                pol1 = 0
                oth1 = 0
            End If
        ElseIf pol > 0 Then
            If remain > pol Then
                pol1 = pol
                remain2 = remain - pol
                If oth > 0 Then
                    If remain2 > oth Then
                        oth1 = oth
                    Else
                        oth1 = remain2
                    End If
                Else
                    oth1 = remain2
                End If
            Else
                pol1 = remain
                oth1 = 0
            End If
        ElseIf oth > 0 Then
            If remain > oth Then
                oth1 = oth
            Else
                oth1 = remain
            End If
        End If
    Else
        supmat1 = CDec(txtFund.Text)
        legal1 = 0
        pol1 = 0
        oth1 = 0
    End If

Next
```

i got  the total of 3000 where the output is

```
Supmat = 2000  
Legal = 0  
POL = 1000  
Others = 0
```

but the output i need is

```
Supmat = 2000  
Legal = 0  
POL = 600  
Others = 400
```

if you check my category i inputted the Supmat 2000 first then POL 500 then Others 400 and last is POL 500 again. i only need to get the total of 3000 but since the last POL is 500 i should only get the 100 from it. since i already have the 2000 + 500 + 400 from the first three.

can someone help with the code where whatever i inputted in my datagridview that should be displayed first instead of getting the total of every category.

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpglS.png)

I attached a sample picture on how i want my output is.
the code above can do the output

```
    Supmat = 2000  
    Legal = 0  
    POL = 1000  
    Others = 0
```

Comment: You say the output you need is `POL = 600`, but you're getting `POL = 1000`...because your calculation specifically sets it to 1000. So, why do you say it should be 600? Based on what?

Comment: if you check my category i inputted the supmat 2000 first then pol 500 then others 400 and last is pol 500 again. i only need to get the total of 3000 but since the last pol is 500 i should only get the 100 from it. since i already have the 2000 + 500 + 400 from the first three.

Comment: You should edit your question to include details (such as that) that you left out.

Comment: What I mean is, you have a bunch of calculations happening based on different conditions, did you come up with that calculation on your own (_did you just make it up?_) or do you have some documented requirements detailing how to calculate things? Your calculation logic is obviously wrong, but I can't tell you what's wrong with it if I don't know what the requirements are.

Comment: @ChaseRocker yes i just made it up. i have a txtFund.Text that i can input any amount. and a datagridview that has category and amount. now i have 4 textboxes to show my total per category. and another 4 textboxes for the output i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... Loop thru your data passing the total value and each subtotal value to `calcTotal` which handles the actual calculations and updates the totals. When the total value <= 0, exit the loop.

```
Private Sub MainCalculation()
    Dim supmat As Decimal = 0
    Dim legal As Decimal = 0
    Dim pol As Decimal = 0
    Dim oth As Decimal = 0
    Dim total_value As Decimal = CDec(Me.txtFund.Text)

    For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        Dim t As Decimal = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Amount").Value

        Select Case DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Category").Value
            Case "Supplies/Materials"
                calcTotal(supmat, total_value, t)
            Case "Legal Expenses"
                calcTotal(legal, total_value, t)
            Case "POL"
                calcTotal(pol, total_value, t)
            Case "Others"
                calcTotal(oth, total_value, t)
        End Select

        If total_value <= 0 Then Exit For
    Next

    Debug.Print("Supmat = " & supmat)
    Debug.Print("Legal = " & legal)
    Debug.Print("POL = " & pol)
    Debug.Print("Others = " & oth)
End Sub

Private Sub calcTotal(ByRef subtotal As Decimal, ByRef total_value As Decimal, t As Decimal)
    If total_value > t Then
        subtotal += t
        total_value -= t
    Else
        subtotal += total_value
        total_value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```